# how to show img in JSP as a saved FileItem Object in a ArrayList?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I need to add photo in my JSP project. I did it in the same way as [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm) suggested. I saved it as a FileItem in an ArrayList (Serialization). Then I sent it again as ArrayList by the help of Servlet. But currently I can't figure out how to view them in JSP

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us the code you have so far, then it's much easier to help you.

Comment: I hid the link using [] and ().